# Storing a Key Value Array into a compact JSON string

Tags: json, key-value

I want to store an array of key value items, a common way to do this could be something like:

```
// the JSON data may store several data types, not just key value lists,
// but, must be able to identify some data as a key value list

// --> more "common" way to store a key value array
{
  [
    {"key": "slide0001.html", "value": "Looking Ahead"},
    {"key": "slide0008.html", "value": "Forecast"},
    {"key": "slide0021.html", "value": "Summary"},
    // another THOUSANDS KEY VALUE PAIRS
    // ...
  ],
  "otherdata" : { "one": "1", "two": "2", "three": "3" }
}
```

But, when there is many pairs / items, the string length becomes prohibited,
and I want a compact way, this could be an example:

```
// --> (1) a "compact" way to store a key value array
{    
  [
      {"slide0001.html", "Looking Ahead"},
      {"slide0008.html", "Forecast"},
      {"slide0021.html", "Summary"},
      // another THOUSANDS KEY VALUE PAIRS
      // ...
  ],
  "otherdata" : { "one": "1", "two": "2", "three": "3" }
}
```

Additionally, I want a way to identify the data as a keyvalue array,
because, I may want to store other data in the same JSON file.
I have these examples:

```
// --> (2) a "compact" way to store a key value array    
{
    "keyvaluelist":
    [
      {"slide0001.html", "Looking Ahead"},
      {"slide0008.html", "Forecast"},
      {"slide0021.html", "Summary"},
      // another THOUSANDS KEY VALUE PAIRS
      // ...
    ],
    "otherdata" : { "one": "1", "two": "2", "three": "3" }
}

// --> (3) a "compact" way to store a key value array    
{
    "mylist":
    {
      "type": "keyvaluearray",
  "data":
    [
        {"slide0001.html", "Looking Ahead"},
        {"slide0008.html", "Forecast"},
        {"slide0021.html", "Summary"},
                    // another THOUSANDS KEY VALUE PAIRS
                    // ...
    ]
    },
    "otherdata" : { "one": "1", "two": "2", "three": "3" }
}
```

What do you thing, which one do you suggest, do you have another way ?
Thanks.

UPDATE 1: Remove invalid code. Javascript => JSON

UPDATE 2: Add non key value data

UPDATE 3: Replace "[" and "]" for "{" and "}" in each key value pair

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the logic parsing this *knows* that `{"key": "slide0001.html", "value": "Looking Ahead"}` is a key/value pair, then you could transform it in an array and hold a few constants specifying which index maps to which key.

For example:

```
var data = ["slide0001.html", "Looking Ahead"];

var C_KEY = 0;
var C_VALUE = 1;

var value = data[C_VALUE];
```

So, now, your data can be:

```
[
    ["slide0001.html", "Looking Ahead"],
    ["slide0008.html", "Forecast"],
    ["slide0021.html", "Summary"]
]
```

If your parsing logic doesn't know ahead of time about the structure of the data, you can add some metadata to describe it. For example:

```
{ meta: { keys: [ "key", "value" ] },
  data: [
    ["slide0001.html", "Looking Ahead"],
    ["slide0008.html", "Forecast"],
    ["slide0021.html", "Summary"]
  ]
}
```

... which would then be handled by the parser.

Comment: Its the case "doesn't know ahead of time about the structure of the data,". Thanks

Answer (score 23):

So why don't you simply use a key-value literal?

```
var params = {
    'slide0001.html': 'Looking Ahead',
    'slide0002.html': 'Forecase',
    ...
};

return params['slide0001.html']; // returns: Looking Ahead
```

Comment: It would be like the first example, but, it won't identify that is a key value array.

Answer (score 4):

To me, this is the most "natural" way to structure such data in JSON, provided that all of the keys are strings.

```
{
    "keyvaluelist": {
        "slide0001.html": "Looking Ahead",
        "slide0008.html": "Forecast",
        "slide0021.html": "Summary"
    },
    "otherdata": {
        "one": "1",
        "two": "2",
        "three": "3"
    },
    "anotherthing": "thing1",
    "onelastthing": "thing2"
}
```

I read this as

```
a JSON object with four elements
    element 1 is a map of key/value pairs named "keyvaluelist",
    element 2 is a map of key/value pairs named "otherdata",
    element 3 is a string named "anotherthing",
    element 4 is a string named "onelastthing"
```

The first element or second element could alternatively be described as objects themselves, of course, with three elements each.

Answer (score 1):

For use key/value pair in json use an object and don't use array

Find name/value in array is hard but in object is easy

Ex:

```js
var exObj = {
  "mainData": {
    "slide0001.html": "Looking Ahead",
    "slide0008.html": "Forecast",
    "slide0021.html": "Summary",
    // another THOUSANDS KEY VALUE PAIRS
    // ...
  },
  "otherdata" : { "one": "1", "two": "2", "three": "3" }
};
var mainData = exObj.mainData;
// for use:
Object.keys(mainData).forEach(function(n,i){
  var v = mainData[n];
  console.log('name' + i + ': ' + n + ', value' + i + ': ' + v);
});

// and string length is minimum
console.log(JSON.stringify(exObj));
console.log(JSON.stringify(exObj).length);
```

Answer (score 0):

2023 solution: using Object.fromEntries()

```
Object.fromEntries([{id: 1}, {id: 2}].map(item => ([item.id, item])));
```

return

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "2": {
        "id": 2
    }
}
```